# How can I trigger a flash remotely and manually?

Tags: flash, slr, wireless-triggers

If I want to do long-exposure photos in which I trigger the flash multiple times to freeze objects in the frame I know I can use the test button of the flash to trigger it manually.

But if I want to be in the frame myself, how can I trigger a flash manually and from a distance during a long-exposure?

Does an off-the-shelf solution exist, or is the only option to wire something together by myself? A solution that ensures the flash gets triggered every `x` seconds would suffice as well.

I have a Canon 550D, two Cactus V5 transceivers, and an old Starblitz BTZ-2000 flash.

Comment: Don't the user manuals with the Cactus V5 transceivers tell you how to use on to transmit and the other to receive? Push the button on the transmitter every time you want the flash to fire.

Comment: To be honest I don't have the Cactus transceivers until this Friday, so didn't take the time to read the manual yet. I had no clue that you could trigger the flash manually with the transceivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a 'Test' button on top of your Cactus tranceivers. Push it (on the one not actually attached to the flash) to fire your flash remotely. Manual available [here](http://www.cactus-image.com/V5%20manual.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your flash has it or not, but some flashes have a strobe mode where you can configure a certain number of flashes with a certain gap in between.  If not, you could certainly use anything that is hotshoe compliant (which I assume the transceivers are) and simply close the circuit between the edge clip and the center post to fire the flash manually.  That's assuming that there isn't an ability to manually fire the transceivers which I don't have any direct experience with.